# .Net 7 Azure function for isolated process compile error with ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-7.0, dotnet-isolated

I'm adding a new azure function (isolated process) to a running .net 7 project, but got the compile error "The attribute 'ServiceBusTrigger' is a WebJobs attribute and not supported in the .NET Worker (isolated process)".

We're using isolated process for .net 7 at the moment and it can't be changed.

Even the simple function generated by chatGPT also can't be built because of that error

> [Function("MyServiceBusTriggerFunction")]
> public static void Run(
> [**ServiceBusTrigger**("", "")]     ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
> FunctionContext context)
> {
> }

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure function worker isolated process .NET 6 - work with servicebus and servicebus trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782038/azure-function-worker-isolated-process-net-6-work-with-servicebus-and-service)

Comment: please check if you have below packages in your .csproj file
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker"  Version="1.10.0"  />
    <PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus"  Version="4.2.1"  />
    <PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk"  Version="1.7.0"  />

Comment: Would this solution work with .NET 7?

Comment: Yes, It worked for me and even I am using .NET 7 isolated process

Comment: It works, thank you Ikhtesam Afrin @IkhtesamAfrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I have reproduced the issue at my environment using .Net 7 isolated process with service Bus triggered function and got the expected result***

> **The attribute 'ServiceBusTrigger' is a WebJobs attribute and not supported in the .NET Worker (isolated process)**

Please check if you have below items in your .csproj file.
You can refer to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993652/the-attribute-tableattribute-is-a-webjobs-attribute-and-not-supported-in-the) for more details about the error.

```
<ItemGroup>

<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker"  Version="1.10.0"  />
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus"  Version="4.2.1"  />
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk"  Version="1.7.0"  />

</ItemGroup>
```

I have created a default service Bus queue triggered function using VS code.

I have below files created in vs code

[image]

**`Code:`**

```
using  System;
using  Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace  Company.Function
{

public  class  ServiceBusQueueTrigger1
{
private  readonly  ILogger  _logger;
public  ServiceBusQueueTrigger1(ILoggerFactory  loggerFactory)
{
_logger  =  loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ServiceBusQueueTrigger1>();
}
[Function("ServiceBusQueueTrigger1")]
public  void  Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection  =  "afreen001_SERVICEBUS")] string  myQueueItem)
{
_logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
}
}
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"afreen001_SERVICEBUS": "*****************"

}
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]